# Is that possible to create sharepoint list view as gant chart view programically?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, view, gantt-chart

Is that possible to create sharepoint list view as gant chart view programically? I created list view programically refer below code

```
         var web = (SPWeb)properties.Feature.Parent;

        SPList list = web.GetList(SharedDocumentListUrl);
        SPViewCollection allviews = list.Views;
        string viewName = "Document Review Summary";
        System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection viewFields = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        viewFields.Add(EYWorkProductIndicator);
        viewFields.Add(EYPaperProfile);
        viewFields.Add(DocIcon);
                   string myquery = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>In Review</Value></Eq></Where>"
           + "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='LinkFilename' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>";
        SPView customView = allviews.Add(viewName, viewFields, myquery, 100, true, false);
        customView.XslLink = "eymain.xsl";
        customView.Update();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close with what you have here.  In your line where you add the view to the SPViewCollection, you need to use a different overload method.  The list of method options is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spviewcollection_methods.aspx).  You need the one that includes the SPViewCollection.SPViewType type.  This line should look something like this.

```
 SPView customView = allviews.Add(viewName, viewFields, myquery, 100, true, false, SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Gantt, false);
```